# How to loop through file pattren and rename file name in linux?

Tags: linux

I have below file in one directory of linux now i want to shoart like ls -ltr *secu*.meta then i wanted to rename those shorted files from .meta to .xml how can i do that with loop in linux ? i tried coupld of option but no luck my goal is too loop through all file list and find pattren and rename all file to .xml i may need to find another pattren also like ls -ltr *est*.meta to *est*.xml ?? this is just an example i may have more then 5 pattren in search.

```
401409.test_est.meta
301409.test_secu.meta
201409.test_secu.meta
201409.resp_secu.meta
2001409.test_esf.meta
101409.test_secu.meta
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're asking, but I'm assuming you're asking how to move all files called `*.meta` to `.xml`.

Try this:

```
for f in *.meta; do
    mv "$f" "$(basename $f .meta).xml"
done
```

Comment: No thats not my requirement i need to short files ls -ltr *secu*.meta than rename result of sorting, so i need to rename only 4 files in above input which are 301409.test_secu.meta, 201409.test_secu.meta,201409.resp_secu.meta,101409.test_secu.meta, now rename this 4 to .xml from meta ext